# php read file line by line.explode each line and check against some condition and write to another file

Tags: php, html

I have a file readfrom.txt  which has some lines of texts.the format is as follow
my readfrom.txt

```
good=morning
egg=eggcurry
hi=hello
```

my aim is to read this file line by line and then for each line check whether the left part of the equal sign has more then or equal to three characters,and if so write the complete line to another text file writeto.txt.
considering the above mention readfrom.txt,my writeto.txt should contain only the first two lines as the left part of the third line has "hi",which has less then 3 characters it should not be written to the writeto.txt.

my index.php is as follow so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>

<body>


  <?php
$file = fopen("readfrom.txt", "r");
$handle = fopen("writeto.txt", 'a');
while(!feof($file)) {
    $line     = fgets($file); 
    fwrite($handle, $line);

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

According to this code the whole file is used to written to the other file.But my objective is after reading each line from radfrom.txt the program should chech whether the left part of the line(left part of the equal sign) has less then 3 character,if so it should not write that line to the writeto.txt,and if the left part of the line has 3 or more chracter,then the the program should write that line to the writeto.txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use php string `explode` function to split a string into array, and use `strlen` to get length of a string.

```
$file = fopen("readfrom.txt", "r");
$handle = fopen("writeto.txt", 'a');
while(!feof($file)) {
  $line     = fgets($file); 
  $lineAry = explode("=", $line);
  if(strlen($lineAry[0])>=3)   
    fwrite($handle, $line);
}
```